# Why won't my application context appear in the unified audit trail for Oracle 19c?

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I am trying to generate an application context for when I use certain DDL. For the setup, I create the context with the following:

```
create or replace
context MYCTX using MYFUNC;
```

Then I create the function that sets the context as well:

```
create or replace
function myfunc return int is
begin
    dbms_session.set_context('MYCTX','ATTR','mysession');
    return 5;
end;
/
```

This works just fine. Then, if I run this:

```
SELECT myfunc from DUAL;
```

It returns 5 as expected. Then I run:

```
SELECT sys_context('MYCTX','ATTR') from dual;
```

It returns "mysession" without any issues whatsoever.

The problem is when I go to do some DDL statements. Currently, I have Oracle Unified Auditing enabled and I am auditing the CREATE TABLE and DROP TABLE Actions. After ensuring that I have changed the sys_context (from my earlier query), I run these two commands:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLETEST (ID INTEGER);
DROP TABLE TABLETEST;
```

Yet when I query the unified audit trail:

```
SELECT * FROM UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL
ORDER BY EVENT_TIMESTAMP_UTC DESC;
```

the "APPLICATION_CONTEXTS" column is completely blank! What gives? How can I get my application context to show up in this field?

Of course, the long term goal of this would be to set the application context before running a SQL script to easily identify audit logs pertaining to that script at a later date.

What do I need to do to populate the application context for unified auditing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO get the application_context populated you need to enable the audit context. Suppose if you want to capture the service name and user name you can use the below.

audit context namespace userenv attributes session_user, service_name;

try this and you should be good with that.

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution!